# How do you ignore an element with Apache Digester?

Tags: xml, apache-commons-digester

How do I set a digester rule to ignore an element with a certain attribute value? For example, given the below XML and digester-rules, how do I tell it to ignore the Parameter which has a Name equal to "Alex"?

XML:

```
<input-parameters>
    <parameter>
        <name><![CDATA[Steve]]></name>
        <description><![CDATA[Footballer]]></description>
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
        <name><![CDATA[Adam]]></name>
        <description><![CDATA[Author]]></description>
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
        <name><![CDATA[Lynda]]></name>
        <description><![CDATA[Blacksmith]]></description>
    </parameter>
    <parameter> <!--I want to ignore this whole parameter element.-->
        <name><![CDATA[Alex]]></name>
        <description><![CDATA[Showjumper]]></description>
    </parameter>            
</input-parameters>
```

Current XML Rules:

```
<pattern value="input-parameters">
    <object-create-rule classname="java.util.HashSet"/>
    <set-next-rule methodname="addParameters"/>

    <pattern value="parameter">
        <object-create-rule classname="com.foo"/>
        <set-next-rule methodname="add"/>
        <bean-property-setter-rule pattern="name" propertyname="name" />
        <bean-property-setter-rule pattern="description" propertyname="description" />
    </pattern>
</pattern>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think Digester supports this natively, but I can suggest a couple of options that may help to get you there.

Simplest is to just use a custom `HashSet` implementation which rejects the names you don't like:

```
public class MyHashSet extends HashSet<Parameter> {
  @Override
  public boolean add(Parameter param) {
    if (param != null && "Alex".equals(param.getName())) {
      return false;
    }
    return super.add(param);
  }
}
```

And then use this instead of the standard `HashSet` in your rules:

```
<pattern value="input-parameters">
    <object-create-rule classname="com.foo.MyHashSet"/>
    <set-next-rule methodname="addParameters"/>
    ...
</pattern>
```

The main drawback I can see from this approach is that you are left with your custom hash set implementation in your resulting object, so if you later try to add a parameter with name = "Alex" directly from code it will again be rejected; this may or may not be a problem.

A slightly more complex approach would be to switch out the standard `SetNextRule` with a custom implementation which checked the name before adding the parameter. The standard `SetNextRule` fires on the event end, so the following rule would do the trick:

```
public class SetNextParamRule extends SetNextRule {

  public SetNextParamRule() {
    super("add");
  }

  @Override
  public void end(String namespace, String name) throws Exception {
    Parameter param = (Parameter)getChild();
    if (!"Alex".equals(param.getName())) {
      super.end(namespace, name);
    }
  }
}
```

One problem with this approach is that I can't see a way to add custom rules using the XML configuration (I rarely use XML config so could be wrong here), so you would need to use code configuration instead:

```
final Rule setNextParamRule = new SetNextParamRule();

RulesModule rules = new AbstractRulesModule() {
  @Override
  public void configure() {
    forPattern("input-parameters")
        .createObject().ofType(HashSet.class)
        .then().setNext("addParameters");
    forPattern("input-parameters/parameter")
        .createObject().ofType(Parameter.class)
        .then().addRule(setNextParamRule);
    forPattern("input-parameters/parameter/name").setBeanProperty();
    forPattern("input-parameters/parameter/description").setBeanProperty();
  }
};

DigesterLoader loader = DigesterLoader.newLoader(rules);
Digester digester = loader.newDigester();
```

One advantage of this however is that you could potentially supply the list of names to ignore from a separate source:

```
import com.google.common.collect.ImmutableSet;

final Set<String> skipNames = ImmutableSet.of("Alex", "Adam");

final Rule setNextParamRule = new SetNextRule("add") {
  @Override
  public void end(String namespace, String name) throws Exception {
    Parameter param = (Parameter)getChild();
    if (!skipNames.contains(param.getName())) {
      super.end(namespace, name);
    }
  }
};

// rest as above
```

Hope some of this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the fantastically in-depth answer! Much obliged.
My low-tech solution was just to loop over the resulting HashSet and remove anything where parameter.getName().equals("Alex").